Accessing a position that does not exist
I am using intel fortran and could not figure out why I don't get an error when accessing a position in a matrix that doesn't exist.
I have a matrix umf3 with dimensions (36,6, 3,960,15). If I print the size of each dimension, it prints them correctly
print*,'Size', size(umf3,1), size(umf3,2), size(umf3,3), size(umf3,4), size(umf3,5)
Size          36           6           3         960          15

In theory, if I write a print statement indicating number 10 in dimension 2 it should give me an error, but it does not
print*,'umf3',umf3(36,10,3,960,15)
 8.54886961063891 

Do you have any idea why this can be happening? Thanks!
Just in case I am using the following line to compile
ifort mod_data.f90 sub_c_exp.f90 sub_distribution.f90 sub_final_wages.f90 sub_matching_data.f90 sub_tgrid.f90 sub_wages.f90 sub_couples3.f90 main2.f90 -heap-arrays

I tried creating a new matrix with other name to see if it was a memory problem (some old matrix in the memory) but it still works without giving me errors

The compiler is not required to check for these errors. It is your responsibility to only access those indexes that belong to the array. If you wish additional checks, enable them with options like ifx -g -check -warn (or with older ifort instead of the current ifx). Note that the checks will make the program run slower.

Fortran is oriented to get high performances, so the compilers do not generate runtime checks like bound checking by default. Runtime checks can be enabled during the development in debug mode.

Thanks a lot Vladimir and Pier. As you suggested, I added checks and with that I could get the appropriate errors. In general, even without adding the checks the compiler used to point out these errors, but it did not in the current program. Thanks!
